# Is there a technology that provides cross domain browser to browser communication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, html

I would like to use the technology to reduce network load.  Preferably I would like to use something that doesn't require a plugin but any solution will help.  Maybe chat roulette did something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't such standard cross browser technology. Chat roulette uses Flash. A plugin will be required in any case.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 with saving local data - for caching - this might reduce the network load. Maybe by means of the same locale data you might allow browser communication. I ack I am not sure about these strategies, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with the BitTorrent protocol, if you can implement that. If you want a chat function, I'm pretty sure flash is the easiest and fastest way. Otherwise, you have to send data to a remote server, which will relay it to the clients and that isn't cross domain, as you want it to be.